# cellForRowAtIndex not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am populating a UITableView in a `ViewController` as a `UISearchController` with Google Autocomplete.  However, `cellForRowAtIndex` isn't getting called the breakpoint does nothing.

What I have checked;

- Datasource set to self
- Delegate set to self
- Data is being printed out in the console
- I have all delegate and Datasource methods

Although, when I implement the same code with the `UISearchController` as the same as the main `ViewController` it works fine.  Could this be as the `UISearchController` is a different `ViewController`?

Any thought? Any help greatly appreciated.- Code Below;

### MapController

```
class MapController: UIViewController {

private let resultsController = ResultsController()
private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: ResultsController())
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GoogleMapsService.shared.configureMapView(to: self)
    GoogleMapsService.shared.googleMapsView.delegate = self
    configureNavigationController()
    edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    configureLocationManager()
}

func configureNavigationController() {
    guard let navigationController = navigationController else { return }
    navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.delegate = resultsController
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
    searchController.configureSearchController()
    }
}
```

### ResultsController

```
class ResultsController: UIViewController {

    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private let searchResultsCellIdentifier = "searchResultsCellIdentifier"
    private var gmsPlacesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    private var searchResults = [GMSAutocompletePrediction]()

    lazy var filteredResults: GMSAutocompleteFilter = {
        let filteredResults = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        filteredResults.type = .address
        return filteredResults
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureTableView()
    }

    func configureTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor,
                         paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0,
                         width: 0, height: 0)
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.register(ResultsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: searchResultsCellIdentifier)
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 243/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}

extension ResultsController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchResultsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: searchResultsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ResultsCell
        let result = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        searchResultsCell.result = result
        return searchResultsCell
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `resultsController` and the argument of `searchResultsController` are two different objects. The default initializer `ResultsController()` creates always a new instance.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint in `tableView :numberOfRowsInSection:`? What is the value of `searchResults.count`?

Comment: setting breakpoint at numberOfRows gives me; 
searchResults [GMSAutocompletePrediction] 0 values
which is correct upon selecting the searchBar

Comment: @vadian do you have a more efficient example of setting up the  
 UISearchController in another    ViewController?

Comment: Maybe this change would work `private lazy var searchController : UISearchController = { return UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController) }()` The change makes sure that only one instance of the controller is used.

Comment: @vadian it looks like this has solved my problem - please add as an answer so I can accept if everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different instances of `ResultsController` because each call of the default initializer `ResultsController()` creates a new instance.

A solution is to declare `searchController` lazily.

```
private lazy var searchController : UISearchController = { 
    return UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController) 
}()
```